# Manually Stopping Single Email Journeys?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

My company sends our single emails out in Journey Builder so that we can leverage Einstein STO, Path Optimizer A&B tests, and other segmentation splits. These "journeys" are always running, even after the send. This journey will never be used again. Should I be manually stopping these journeys after everyone in my Data Extension has received the email? It's a little confusing to see a journey running from months ago, and there is always a little fear that these Data Extensions might get updated somehow and these old emails would be sent out to new DE records.
Is there a better way to do this than manually stopping the journey each time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can stop them, if the same journey need to be re-used in future you can create a new version of respective journey and update the emails before activating them.